# Increase nominal value of a text insid variable?

Tags: javascript, java, variables

How I can increase this text value inside my variable ?

For example, a file name inside the folder

```
fileNAME = '1';
```

Later in the script I need to do a variable have a number and need to set this number to the fileNAME:

```
newNumber++;
```

and need to set to newNumber value:

```
fileNAME = '*newNumber*';
```

Here what am not sure how to do this.

Here the full script

```
// Listing item menu
// Listi= test premiere list
Itemlist = 1; // test itemid 1 in DB
Listi=1; // List loop (while) Listi/ max item show in screen
Pid = 100; // Picture id (100-1 eatch loop)
Xitem = 0; // X coor for the item + picturesize+ marge
Yitem = 0; // Y coor for the item + picturesize+ marge
InpicX = 46; // Initial X of menue item list
InpicY = 186; // Initial Y of menue item list
MargeX = 7; // Marge bettwenn 2 picture X 
MargeY = 6; // Marge bettwenn 2 picture Y
ISIZEX = 82; // X size of picture
ISIZEY = 82; // X size of picture
fileNAME = '1';// identifie le nom fichier 1,2,3,4,5,6 .....
PIDNAME = 0 // identifie le nom de limage a id de limage 
// Test if have item
while(Listi<=36){
if (($gameParty.hasItem($dataItems[Itemlist])==true || $dataItems[Itemlist].itypeId !== 2) || $dataItems[Itemlist].itypeId !== 3){
$gameScreen.showPicture(Pid, fileNAME, 0, InpicX+Xitem, InpicY+Yitem, 100, 100, 255, 0);
$gameScreen.setPictureCallCommon(Pid, 21, 1);
// cré une variable PIDNAME [X] selon le pid ex: si clic sur image 200 , variable volatile PIDNAME= LE NOM DE FICHIER 
PIDNAME[Pid] = $gameScreen._pictures[Pid]._name;
if (Listi==12 || Listi==24  || Listi==36) {
    Xitem=0; Yitem+=ISIZEY+MargeY; Itemlist++; Listi++; Pid++;
}else{Xitem+=ISIZEX+MargeX; Itemlist++; Listi++; Pid++;}
}else {Itemlist++;}}
```

Comment: why do you need to have an Int as a String? If it's for concatenation, you can just go ahead and concatenate Int with Strings.

Comment: i update my question is for a game :)

Comment: use fileNAME = newNumber.toString(); or fileNAME=""+newNumber;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your file name to an int.

```
currentFileNumber=parseInt(fileNAME);
```

Then increment the number.

```
currentFileNumber++;
```

Finally, convert the file number to a string and use it for your purpose.

```
fileNAME=currentFileNumber.toString();
```

**Or More easily**

Keep a variable to track your current file number.

```
fileNumber=1;
```

Increment it whenever you want to.

```
fileNumber++;
```

Then convert that to string to get the string representation.

```
fileName=fileNumber.toString();
```

Comment: Ho tanks you is thats a need friend .

Answer (score 0):

Ok found best solution.
Here guys

fileNames =  **Number**("1");

fileNames++;

fileNames=**String**(fileNames);

Work good for me